# Does terminal voltage change when adding a resistor in series?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

I was under the impression that the potential difference from the source of a circuit does not change when you add a resistor, either series or parallel. However, my textbook says otherwise based on a reading comprehension quiz:

> Consider the following choices: (a) increases, (b) decreases, (c) remains the same. From these choices, choose the best answer for the following situations. (i) In Active Figure 28.3, a third resistor is added in series with the first two. What happens to the current in the battery? (ii) What happens to the terminal voltage of the battery? (iii) In Active Figure 28.5, a third resistor is added in parallel with the first two. What happens to the current in the battery? (iv) What happens to the terminal voltage of the battery?

For reference, this is Active Figure 28.3:
[image]

and this is 28.5:
[image]

The textbook says that the correct choices should be (b), (a), (a), and (b). Whereas I believe it should be (c) for both the second and fourth parts. How could the terminal voltage of the battery change just by putting another resistor into the circuit?

Comment: The battery has an internal resistance and it's own voltage drop that follows Ohm's law.

Comment: @DavidWhite But the schematics show ideal voltage sources in place of the battery.

Comment: Wouldn't the circuit diagrams show the internal resistors of the batteries?

Comment: @electro, I'm giving you the primary reason for the answers that you quoted.  Apparently, the question wanted you to realize that the batteries have internal resistance, and they deliberately didn't give you that information in the schematic diagrams.